# Clarifying the action of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbf{H}^2$.

Tags: group-actions

I’m working my way up towards understanding the proof of the fact that the geodesic flow on $\mathbf{H}^2$ (the hyperbolic space) is ergodic, and, in doing so, I’ve come across the group $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R}) = \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\lbrace\pm I_2\rbrace$, where $I_2$ denotes the $2\times2$ identity matrix, repeatedly, and I’d just like a little bit of help clarifying the action of this group on $\mathbf{H}^2$. In particular, in Bekka’s book, $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is said to act on $\mathbf{H}^2$ by
$$
gz = \frac{a + bz}{c + dz},\quad g\in\mathbf{H}^2,\quad g=\left(\begin{array}{c c}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}).
$$
I was basically wondering the following: since $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a quotient group, its elements are given, using set comprehension, by
$$
\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})=\lbrace\lbrace g,-g\rbrace:g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\rbrace,
$$
and yet the action of this group on $\mathbf{H}^2$ seems to ignore this completely, and just makes use of the elements of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, directly. What, therefore, is the significance of taking the quotient of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, and defining *its* action on $\mathbf{H}^2$, instead of just using $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, directly? Moreover, what even is the point of taking this quotient? Intuitively, I imagine we take this quotient because the orbits of the point $z\in\mathbf{H}^2$ under $g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $-g$ are identical, but is this the sole reason for working with this quotient in the context of hyperbolic geometry? As an aside, my group theory is very (*very*) minimal, so it’s probably in your best interest to explain this to me like I’m a 5-year-old, sorry! Any help in this regard is kindly appreciated.

Comment: If you think of it as an action of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ then it's not faithful. Its kernel is exactly the center, and quotienting by this kernel gives you $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. So it's $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ that acts faithfully.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I just want to clarify a few things about your comment: firstly, by "the center" of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, you mean $\lbrace\pm I_2\rbrace$. Since $\pm I_2z = z$, for all $z\in\mathbf{H}^2$, the action of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is not a faithful action, as you said. On the other hand, by taking the quotient of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, we identify $I_2$ with $-I_2$, so $I_2$ and $-I_2$, as elements of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, produce the same action on $\mathbf{H}^2$. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: You mean "as elements of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$," but other than that, yes.

Comment: Besides making actions faithful, using $PSL$ instead of $SL$ also means the action of $PSL_2\Bbb R$ on the tangent bundle of the upper half-plane is *regular* (or *sharply* transitive), and similarly the action of $PSL_2\Bbb C$ on the Riemann sphere is *sharply* $3$-transitive.